# How to import bootstrap js library into a nextjs project?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, bootstrap-5

I want to use Bootstrap in my nextjs project which is server side rendering.

After few of studing, I write to import bootstrap in my root layout with this:

```
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
import "./globals.css";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

export const metadata = {
  title: "Create Next App",
  description: "Generated by create next app",
};

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
      require("bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js");
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>{children}</body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

But it give me a warning that I can't use useEffect without "use client" mode.

```
You're importing a component that needs useEffect. It only works in a Client Component but none of its parents are marked with "use client", so they're Server Components by default.
Learn more: https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/react-essentials
```

Because I want my webapp render at server side, therefore I dont' think I should use "use client" in the root component, how can I import the js library correctly?

Answer (score 0):

> I dont' think I should use "use client" in the root component,

You can do this in another component & simply import in `layout.tsx` file. Doing it this way will do it.

New component to just import the library

BootstrapForBrowser.tsx

```
'use client';

import "bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js";
import { Fragment } from "react";

function BootstrapForBrowser() {
  return <Fragment></Fragment>;
} 

export default BootstrapForBrowser;
```

Layout.tsx

```
import Bootstrap from "./Component/BootstrapForBrowser";

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {

  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>{children}</body>
      <Bootstrap />
    </html>
  );
}
```

Thats it! In the future, you can extend the `BootstrapForBrowser` component to load other client side libraries too.